# facing an issue with Angular filter

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add search box in my angular template where user can type any character and system will filter data from different tables based on user input. If no student found than i want to show message 'No matching student found'

Here what i am trying to do.

**Problem i am facing is**

> It always show 'No matching student found message' regardless of search outcome.

```
<div>
 <input type="text" ng-model="searchStudent">
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="studentPermissions in studentPermissions">
        <div ng-repeat="student in studentPermissions.entities">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td >Student</td>
                        <td>{{student.StudentName}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th ng-repeat="permission in student.entityStudents[0].userPermissions"><div><span>{{permission.Name}}</span></div></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="student in student.entityStudents | filter:searchStudent">
                        <td>{{student.FirstName}} {{student.LastName}}</td>
                        <td ng-repeat="permission in student.userPermissions">
                            <input ng-model="permission.Checked" type="checkbox">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-show="!(student.entityStudents | filter:searchStudent).length">
    No match student found
</div>
```

Comment: you are accessing `student.entityStudents` outside its scope and it will be always null

Comment: Does it filter the results and also shows "No match student found"

Comment: @ Dev-One yes it filters and shows message as well.

Comment: @ Sappy Goofy, thanks for confirming my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Pls give me plunkr that will help me to answer your question
I think the problem is you directly wrote no matching found you haven't wrote {{student.entityStudents}} or whatever your variable name is

Here is the problem a typo `<div ng-repeat="studentPermissions in studentPermissions">` you having same name for both of the varibles

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by global scope variable in controller based on search outcome and than showing / not showing message on UI.